# Microsoft Azure for MySQL can't connect to DB using PHP

Tags: php, database, azure

Goodmorning to all,
I'm trying to connect to my Azure server for MySQL using php but it gives me an error. The php file runs every day at 00:00 on a server where my website is hosted and must connect to the azure DB to run queries on the Azure DB.
The error I get is "connection timed out" i've tried to add in my firewall the rule with the ip of my server with the sample command: " az mysql server firewall-rule create --resource-group myresourcegroup --server mydemoserver --name AllowMyIP --start-ip-address 192.168.0.1 --end-ip-address 192.168.0.1 " obviously changing the values but it fails...
I attach the code below:

```php
$conAzure = mysqli_init();
        mysqli_ssl_set($conAzure, NULL, NULL, "pathToSSLCert",NULL, NULL);
        mysqli_real_connect($conAzure, "test.mysql.database.azure.com", "test@test", "test", "proj_sophie", 3306, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

        // Check connection
        if ($conAzure->connect_error) {
// THE PROGRAM STOPS HERE
            die("Connection failed: " . $conAzure->connect_error);
        }
        echo "Connected successfully";

        $sqlAzure1 = "TRUNCATE TABLE elenco_post;";
            if ($conAzure->query($sqlAzure1) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sqlAzure1 . "<br>" . $conAzure->error;
            }

// inserting in the selected table and fields the data (it's in a for-each so don't worry for the repetitions).
$sqlAzure2 = "INSERT INTO elenco_post ('ID', 'Titolo', 'Contenuto', 'Data', 'URL', 'Ultima_Modifica', 'URL_Immagine', 'Nome_immagine', 'Categoria') VALUES ('".get_the_ID()."',
                    '".get_the_title()."',
                    '".get_the_content()."',
                    '".get_the_date()."',
                    '".get_permalink()."',
                    '".get_the_modified_date()."',
                    '".get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full')."',
                    '".get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title."',
                    '".$category."');";
            if ($conAzure->query($sqlAzure2) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sqlAzure2 . "<br>" . $conAzure->error;
            }
```

Thank you, waiting for support!

Answer (score 0):

> --start-ip-address 192.168.0.1

This looks very improbable for a client address running in Azure. Where is your PHP running? I suspect you are running it on a home PC in a masqueraded LAN - in which case that's **not** the IP address which is connecting to Azure, merely the address you use to connect to your router.

Try https://whatismyipaddress.com/ to find out what your address is right now - but if I'm right, it will change regularly.

Comment: Hi, I obviously changed the IPs, server name and passw. The communication lives between 2 server, first one has a public static IP, second one (Azure) has it's nameserver so I can reach easily.